# Search for string in a text column and list the count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

Ok, I may be asking very stupid question but somehow I am not able to get a way to perform the following.

I have a table that contains two columns as below

```
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SL No |                                                                      Work                                                                       |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1 | Identify Process Champs across all teams for BCUK processes                                                                                     |
|     2 | Impart short training on FMEA to all the Process Champs                                                                                         |
|     2 | List down all critical steps involved in the Process to ascertain the risk involved, feed the details back to FMEA template to analyze the risk |
|     3 | Prioritize the process steps based on Risk Priority Number                                                                                      |
|     4 | Identity the Process Gaps, suggest process improvement ideas to mitigate/mistake proof or reduce the risk involved in the process               |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I have other table that holds the "Key Words" like below

```
+-------+----------+
| Sl No |   Tags   |
+-------+----------+
|     1 | BCUK     |
|     2 | FMEA     |
|     3 | Priority |
|     4 | Process  |
+-------+----------+
```

Now I would like to "Search for String" in first table based on "tags" in second table and return something like this

```
+----------+-------+
|   Tags   | Count |
+----------+-------+
| BCUK     |     1 |
| FMEA     |     2 |
| Priority |     1 |
| Process  |     8 |
+----------+-------+
```

As `"Process"` keyword appears `eight times` in the entire table (first table) across multiple rows it returns the count as 8.

I am using `SQL Server 2014 Express Edition`

Comment: Are there no joins on table? how are they connected? Ok is Sl no join between two tables?

Comment: is your column really a text column ?

Comment: Drive-by comment since I have no time for a proper answer: this sounds like a job for `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Unfortunately no joins, these are two separate table coming from two sources (manual import). As "tags" (table 2) are created by process analyst and gets added or deleted on a monthly basis manually, the first table is imported from a different source. Second column in table 2 is a `text` column

Comment: could you take a look at my answer as well please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam Machanic has a function `GetSubstringCount` for this kind of operations. I modified it a bit for your needs. For more info: http://dataeducation.com/counting-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string/

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    SLNo    INT,
    Work    VARCHAR(4000)
)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
(1, 'Identify Process Champs across all teams for BCUK processes'),
(2, 'Impart short training on FMEA to all the Process Champs'),
(2, 'List down all critical steps involved in the Process to ascertain the risk involved, feed the details back to FMEA template to analyze the risk'),
(3, 'Prioritize the process steps based on Risk Priority Number'),
(4, 'Identity the Process Gaps, suggest process improvement ideas to mitigate/mistake proof or reduce the risk involved in the process');

CREATE TABLE KeyWord(
    SLNo    INT,
    Tag     VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO KeyWord VALUES
(1, 'BCUK'),
(2, 'FMEA'),
(3, 'Priority'),
(4, 'Process');
```

**SOLUTION**

```
;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)
,E2 AS(SELECT 1 AS N FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4 AS(SELECT 1 AS N FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(11000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))FROM E4 a, e4 b
)
SELECT
    k.Tag,
    [Count] = SUM(x.cc)
FROM KeyWord k
CROSS JOIN MyTable m
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cc
    FROM Tally
    WHERE
        SUBSTRING(m.Work, N, LEN(k.tag)) = k.tag
)x
GROUP BY k.tag
```

**RESULT**

```
Tag                  Count
-------------------- -----------
BCUK                 1
FMEA                 2
Priority             1
Process              8
```

Comment: looping through every character to find matches may work, but i imagine it is slow.

Comment: <SUBSTRING(m.Work, N, LEN(k.tag)) = k.tag> checking from first character, second character, third character.....

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: I agree that using a tally is affective looping, but still looping nevertheless. Try creating 500.000 rows in mytable and run your script. Do the same with my script. After that, make sure none of the keywords march and do the same. In the second senario my script script executed in 8 seconds, yours were 86 seconds in both situations

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting the matches, I am replacing them with an extra character and comparing the length with the original length. That way the counting is very easy and fast.

Test tables and data

```
DECLARE @texts table(SL_No int identity(1,1),Work varchar(max))

INSERT @texts VALUES
  ('Identify Process Champs across all teams for BCUK processes'),
  ('Impart short training on FMEA to all the Process Champs'),
  ('List down all critical steps involved in the Process to ascertain the risk involved, feed the details back to FMEA template to analyze the risk'),
  ('Prioritize the process steps based on Risk Priority Number'),
  ('Identity the Process Gaps, suggest process improvement ideas to mitigate/mistake proof or reduce the risk involved in the process')

DECLARE @searchvalues table(S1_No int identity(1,1),Tags varchar(max))

INSERT @searchvalues
VALUES('CUK'),('FMEA'),('Priority'),('Process')
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  sum(len(replace(txt.work, sv.tags, sv.tags + '@')) - len(txt.work)) count, 
  tags
FROM 
  @texts txt
CROSS APPLY
  @searchvalues sv
WHERE charindex(sv.tag, txt.work) > 0
GROUP BY tags
```

Result:

```
count   tags
1   CUK
2   FMEA
1   Priority
8   Process
```